# Can't boot after deleted System Reserved Partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, boot-partition

I only have Windows 7 installed. I accidentally deleted the System Reserved Partition and now I can no longer boot into Windows 7. The installation of Windows and all my files still exist in the partition, but without the System Reserved Partition I can no longer boot.

After I deleted the System Reserved Partition I moved left the primary partition to fill the space.

Is there any way I can "reinstall" that System Reserved Partition and the boot files?

Comment: Try to start **new** installation on **different** partition than you Windows installation exists. At some point - system partition will be restored. Or try to run installer (Windows DVD) in restore mode.

Comment: I can see the files of the old windows installation but not recover from it.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating a small 100 MB partition to the left/before the Win7 partition, as before, *then* running Startup Repair from the DVD?

Comment: I tried that too. After the recommended 3 Startup Repairs, the partition remains empty.

Comment: You need to mark the expanded partition as active using diskpart. This will inform the BIOS that the partition to boot from is your new C:. Then try startup repair.

Answer (score 6):

1. Boot to your Windows DVD
2. Get past startup repair to get a command prompt
3. Type `diskpart` then enter
4. Type `list partition` then enter
5. Make a note of the partition number of your real "C:"
6. Type `select n` where n is the partition number
7. Type `active`
8. Exit diskpart
9. Reboot and run startup repair 3 times.

Comment: I had a similar issue and your solution solved it ! I had a Windows installation on an Extended Partition but deleted the primary boot partition (was another installation of Windows) that was used to boot that second Windows. I created a 100MB primary partition (luckily was the 4th and last) and the rest was your solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a Startup Repair. See this link: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html.

You will need a Windows 7 installation disc to do this since you can't access Windows tools on your hard disk.

Comment: I tried Startup Repair. sometimes it will just say it finished and restart, but still doesn't boot. Other times it'll just say Startup Repair is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to restore the System Reserved Partition. You can use a software like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to do that.

> After I deleted the System Reserved Partition I moved left the primary partition to fill the space.

Nevertheless, you have rewrite this partition when you done that. So, maybe you can still restore her but I'm not really optimistic... Sometimes it's work fine but in the other case the damage are just too consequent...

An other way would be to rebuild the Boot Configuration Data (BCD). Instead of using the Startup Repair, use [the command line with Bootrec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2004518).